# Bitmap Factory Out of Memory

Tags: android, bitmap, factory

I was recently trying to use a large bitmap and put it into my app using decoderesources of the bitmap factory.  I was wondering what the problem is and why I keep getting a VM out of budget error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming this question is for Android.

If so, BitmapFactory leaks memory because the VM budget is full.  The reason the VM budget is full is because the images are too large and the space for allocating such images is ONLY so much.  So you either have to decrease the size of you image or scale it using createscaledbitmap().  This is not your fault, this is an Android bug. It has been asked too many times on this site.

Thanks,